# Методы отрисовки View android

Tags: java, android, методы, view

Какие есть методы отрисовки View и в каком порядке они вызываются?

P.S. В Гугле не забанили, но информации там я почти не нашёл

Comment: https://tuhub.ru/posts/realizatsiya-custom-view-komponenta-v-android

Comment: @pavlofff, премного благодарен)